# How to display nested dependent dynamic data in drop down with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu, flutter-layout

I have a json data, I want to display it in drop down such that initial one drop down will shown with name and upon selecting on that it should display child drop down and each child drop down has its own children as well.

```
class LocationDetail {
  final String name;
  final String id;
  final String categoryId;
  final List<LocationDetail>? childrens;

  const LocationDetail({
    required this.name,
    required this.id,
    required this.categoryId,
    this.childrens,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'id': id,
      'categoryId': categoryId,
      'childrens': childrens,
    };
  }

  factory LocationDetail.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    List<LocationDetail> childrens = [];
    if (map['childrens'] != null) {
      map['childrens'].forEach((v) {
        childrens.add(LocationDetail.fromMap(v));
      });
    }
    return LocationDetail(
      name: map['name'] as String,
      id: map['id'] as String,
      categoryId: map['categoryId'] as String,
      childrens: childrens,
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the location.json data

```
[
  {
    "name": "NewYork",
    "id": "NY",
    "categoryId": "A",
    "childrens": [
      {
        "name": "Rental Car 1",
        "id": "NY-Rental Car1",
        "categoryId": "T1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Rental Car 2",
        "id": "NY-Rental Car2",
        "categoryId": "T2",
        "childrens": [
          {
            "name": "Rental Car 21",
            "id": "NY-Rental Car21",
            "categoryId": "T21"
          },
          {
            "name": "Rental Car 22",
            "id": "NY-Rental Car22",
            "categoryId": "T22"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is how I am reading json and converting to List of locationDetail

```
  class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<LocationDetail>>(
        future: _getJsonData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            // all the  drop down will come here
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
            );
          } else {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<List<LocationDetail>> _getJsonData() async {
    final contents = await rootBundle.loadString(
      'assets/location.json',
    );
    List<dynamic> dataList = jsonDecode(contents);
    List<LocationDetail> locationList =
        dataList.map((v) => LocationDetail.fromMap(v)).toList();
    return locationList;
  }
}
```

Expected Output:

1. Initially only one drop down should show which contain only **NewYork**.
2. Upon selection on **NewYork** should show one more drop down  which contains **Rental Car 1** and **Rental Car 2**.
3. If **Rental Car 1** is selected nothing should happened since that is the last node.
4. If **Rental Car 2** is selected one more drop down should show to select **Rental Car 21** or **Rental Car 22**.
5. Same should happened till we reach to end.

P.S Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I got nothing @MendelG, Logic seems complicated. all resources are link to limited drop down and mine is dynamic. Would be very helpful if you could provide me an approach or solution if possible. I am still trying

Comment: Please show how are you instantiating the `locationDetails` class

Comment: does this help? let me know if I can provide more detail. Thanks